# Obtener un atributo al hacer click sobre un div o sobre sus children React

Tags: reactjs

Estoy recibiendo un array en la prop products que son productos con su costo e imagen, de el contexto coinsContext obtengo coinsFigure que es la cantidad de coins que tiene un usuario, yo quiero que cuando se haga click sobre el div con clase cardContainer, mediante el evento onclick llame la función newFigure y obtenga lo que este en atribute figure que tiene la resta de la cantidad de dinero que tiene el usuario menos el costo del producto, para luego actualizar el estado global.

ahora esto solo me sirve cuando le doy click sobre ese div, pero yo quiero que esto pase cuando yo le de click tanto al div como a su contenido  (children) dentro como la imagen etc. pero así como lo tengo si hago click en los children me arroja null.

como puedo hacer para propagar el evento para que al hacer click en cualquier parte me obtenga el atributo figure que necesito

Gracia por la ayuda

```
function ProductCard({products}) {
    
    const {coinsFigure, updateCoinsFigure} = useContext(CoinsContext);

    const newFigure = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute('figure'))
    }


    return (
        <CardProduct className='d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between w-100'>
            {
                products.map((product)=>{
                    return (
                    <div  key={product.name} onClick={newFigure} figure={coinsFigure - product.cost} className='cardContainer mb-5 position-relative pt-3 pl-3'>
                        {
                             coinsFigure < product.cost ? 
                             <h4 className="position-absolute noBuy">
                                 te faltan {product.cost - coinsFigure}
                                <FontAwesomeIcon className="ml-3" icon={faCoins} />
                            </h4>: 
                            <h4 className="position-absolute buy"><FontAwesomeIcon className="ml-3" icon={faShoppingBag} />{product.cost}</h4>
                        }
                       
                        <div className="imgContainer">
                            <img src={product.img.url} alt={product.name} />
                        </div>
                        <div className='description'>
                            <h4 className='text-center mb-1 mt-3'>{product.name}</h4>
                            <h5 className='text-center pb-4'>{product.category}</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </CardProduct>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que e.target te agarra el elemento que se le hizo click... por eso no tiene la propiedad figure...

Para tener el evento del elemento que si tiene el evento onClick(), tienes que usar
e.currentTarget,

Así quedaría:

```
function ProductCard({products}) {
    
    const {coinsFigure, updateCoinsFigure} = useContext(CoinsContext);

    const newFigure = (e) => {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('figure'))
    }


    return (
        <CardProduct className='d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between w-100'>
            {
                products.map((product)=>{
                    return (
                    <div  key={product.name} onClick={newFigure} figure={coinsFigure - product.cost} className='cardContainer mb-5 position-relative pt-3 pl-3'>
                        {
                             coinsFigure < product.cost ? 
                             <h4 className="position-absolute noBuy">
                                 te faltan {product.cost - coinsFigure}
                                <FontAwesomeIcon className="ml-3" icon={faCoins} />
                            </h4>: 
                            <h4 className="position-absolute buy"><FontAwesomeIcon className="ml-3" icon={faShoppingBag} />{product.cost}</h4>
                        }
                       
                        <div className="imgContainer">
                            <img src={product.img.url} alt={product.name} />
                        </div>
                        <div className='description'>
                            <h4 className='text-center mb-1 mt-3'>{product.name}</h4>
                            <h5 className='text-center pb-4'>{product.category}</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </CardProduct>
    )
}
```